# How can I convert an array to a list without using Arrays.asList() method or Java List Interface

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, linked-list

I got my `Node` class:

```
public class Node <T> {

    private Node<T> next;
    private T element;

    public void setElement(T element) {
        this.element = element; 
    }

    public T getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    public Node<T> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node <T> next) {
        this.next= next;
    }
}
```

And also I have my `List` class:

```
public class List <T> {

Node<T> first;
Node<T> last;
```

...on which I can do various things like adding elements to my list or replacing them, erase some elements, see the size of my list etc. One example of these methods would be `addFirst()`.

```
public T addFirst(T element) {

    Node<T> aux;

    if (isEmpty()) {
        aux = new Node<>();
        first= aux;
        lsat= aux;
        aux.setElement(element);
    } else {
        aux = new Node<>();
        aux.setElement(element);
        aux.setNext(first);
        first= aux;
    }

    return first.getElement();
}
```

I am only missing one method convert an array to a list obviously with the previous mentioned restrictions.

Comment: Hey! Now what is the problem or your question?

Comment: You say you want to convert to a list but with some restrictions, so does that mean you want to convert to a java.util.List and not your own List class? Otherwise I don't understand the restrictions. Also could you add an example of the conversion with regards to input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to loop through the array and simply fill you `List`:

```
// your array of Nodes
Node<?>[] nodeArray = new Node[]{node1,node2,node3,node4,node5};

// your List
List<?> myList = new List<>();

for(Node<?> node : nodeArray)
{
    myList.addLast(node); // use addLast() to keep the same order as the array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over the array with for loop. And call `addFirst()` function in every iteration.

```
Node a[] = new Node[]{node1,node2,node3,node4};
for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
  yourListObject.addFirst(a[i]);
}
```